# Hawtio-online - No containers are showing

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, hawtio, jolokia

I am using hawtio-online for the management of Apache Camel routes. I have an microservice which uses Apache camel framework and running in kubernetes cluster. I had also deployed hawtio-online in my cluster. And added java-jolokia docker image as a init container to my microservice container. When I am accessing hawtio-online its showing like, There are no containers running with a port configured whose name is jolokia.

I am not understanding actually what is it meant by port configured whose name is jolokia.
I have pods running in kubernetes but the hawtio-online is not picking them.

T had searched a lot in internet but i am not getting any perfect blog or article based on hawtio-online.
Can someone help me in finding a solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, you might be logged is as a user with `viewer` permissions, while you need `admin`

Access management a bit tricky if you're using Form authentication, but you  simply need to add `update` verb to `pod` permissions for the role

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-online/blob/main/docs/rbac.md#roles

Also if you are installing hawtio-online, it doesn't come with Role and RoleBinding, so you can take those from Hawtio-operator (just don't forget to add the verb)
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-operator/tree/main/deploy

Unfortunately Hawtio's documentation is a mess and more answers could be found in github's readmes than on official website

EDIT: Forgot to add: for Camel you have to enable Jolokia traits for every integration you're interested in

https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/1.11.x/traits/jolokia.html